# Remove duplicate faces sharing vertices

Tags: modeling, faces

I'd like to know if there is an easy way of deleting all faces which share ALL of their vertices with another face.

I imported a model from a .dae file and merged vertices by distance. This has created strange 'double' faces whose vertices are completely shared.

I can manually delete the duplicate faces one at a time, and a single face remains.

[image: All the face's vertices are shared with the one beneath]

[image: I can select and delete one face]

[image: The other face remains]

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if you can call it from the UI, but the `validate` Python function will remove the extra face. Switch to Object mode, select the object you want to fix, and run this in the Python console

```
C.object.data.validate()
```

Comment: Great! This line immediately **deletes double-sided faces** (so if two faces use the same set of vertices in a different order, only one face will be kept)

Answer (score 1):

Merging points by distance should take the desired effect. In edit mode go to mesh - clean up - merge by distance, or select the geometry then M - by distance.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply - perhaps I didn't explain very well, but I've already merged the points by distance. There are only 4 vertices in total which the two faces completely share.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem and solved it with the triangulate modifier, applying it removes the dup faces. After that you can return to quads with *Tris to Quads* (<kbd>Alt</kbd> +  <kbd>J</kbd>) command.